# SplunkMint lib throwing exception, SocketException: shutdown failed: EBADF

Tags: android, splunk

I started using [Splunk MINT](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/products/splunk-mint.html) and it is working fine, but throwing so many exceptions to my logcat and i would like to do get rid of them.

```
04-01 11:18:03.142: W/System.err(21409): com.splunk.mint.network.util.DelegationException: java.net.SocketException: shutdown failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    04-01 11:18:03.143: W/System.err(21409):    at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke0(Delegator.java:62)
    04-01 11:18:03.143: W/System.err(21409):    at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke(Delegator.java:45)
    04-01 11:18:03.143: W/System.err(21409):    at com.splunk.mint.network.socket.MonitoringSocketImpl.shutdownOutput(MonitoringSocketImpl.java:417)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409):    at java.net.Socket.shutdownOutput(Socket.java:652)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:195)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:161)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.closeConnection(AbstractConnPool.java:320)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.shutdown(ConnPoolByRoute.java:678)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.shutdown(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:256)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.finalize(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:105)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:190)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:173)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    04-01 11:18:03.145: W/System.err(21409): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: shutdown failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    04-01 11:18:03.146: W/System.err(21409):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.shutdownOutput(PlainSocketImpl.java:377)
    04-01 11:18:03.146: W/System.err(21409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    04-01 11:18:03.146: W/System.err(21409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    04-01 11:18:03.146: W/System.err(21409):    at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke0(Delegator.java:56)
    04-01 11:18:03.146: W/System.err(21409):    ... 12 more
    04-01 11:18:03.146: W/System.err(21409): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: shutdown failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    04-01 11:18:03.146: W/System.err(21409):    at libcore.io.Posix.shutdown(Native Method)
    04-01 11:18:03.147: W/System.err(21409):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.shutdown(ForwardingOs.java:149)
    04-01 11:18:03.147: W/System.err(21409):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.shutdownOutput(PlainSocketImpl.java:375)
    04-01 11:18:03.147: W/System.err(21409):    ... 15 more
    04-01 11:18:03.147: W/System.err(21409): com.splunk.mint.network.util.DelegationException: java.net.SocketException: shutdown failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke0(Delegator.java:62)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke(Delegator.java:45)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at com.splunk.mint.network.socket.MonitoringSocketImpl.shutdownInput(MonitoringSocketImpl.java:405)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:633)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:199)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:161)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.closeConnection(AbstractConnPool.java:320)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.shutdown(ConnPoolByRoute.java:678)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.shutdown(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:256)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.finalize(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:105)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:190)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:173)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: shutdown failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    04-01 11:18:03.148: W/System.err(21409):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.shutdownInput(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    04-01 11:18:03.149: W/System.err(21409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    04-01 11:18:03.149: W/System.err(21409):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    04-01 11:18:03.149: W/System.err(21409):    at com.splunk.mint.network.util.Delegator.invoke0(Delegator.java:56)
    04-01 11:18:03.149: W/System.err(21409):    ... 12 more
    04-01 11:18:03.149: W/System.err(21409): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: shutdown failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    04-01 11:18:03.151: W/System.err(21409):    at libcore.io.Posix.shutdown(Native Method)
    04-01 11:18:03.151: W/System.err(21409):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.shutdown(ForwardingOs.java:149)
    04-01 11:18:03.155: W/System.err(21409):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.shutdownInput(PlainSocketImpl.java:363)
    04-01 11:18:03.155: W/System.err(21409):    ... 15 more
```

And filtering logcat is not a solution, can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: 4.08, yesterday i updated to 4.1 and error still remains.

Comment: Seems like a bug, I'd file a contact with them.

Comment: They suggested me to update to 4.1 :)